# Deleting comments from the Comment box (Facebook comment plugin)

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-social-plugins

I'm having problems implementing moderation for the Facebook social plugin comment box. I am implementing it using FBML. I only have the option to report comments as abuse or spam. There is no option to delete the comment.

```
<div>

    <fb:visible-to-connection> 

    <fb:else> 
        <div style="position:relative; top:0px; left: 0px;">
            <imgsrc="http://registration.bforex.com/lps/facebook/EN-non-fan.jpg" border="0" alt="" />     
        </div>
    </fb:else>

    <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left: 0px;">
        <imgsrc="http://registration.bforex.com/lps/facebook/EN-Fan-only.jpg" border="0" alt="" />



    <div id="fb-root"></div>


    <script>
        (function (d, s, id) { var js, fjs =d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return; } js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src ="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); } (document, 'script','facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="facebook.com/bforexTrading#!/bforexTrading?sk=app_190322544333196"
        data-num-posts="2" data-width="450">
    </div>
       </div>
    </fb:visible-to-connection>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

FBML will be deprecated on June 6, 2012.

You cannot link to a Page Tab URL using the comments plugin.

You will have to use an external URL as the href and let that page load the meta data.